# Keep cells format while getting cells values from Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am getting cells value from excel file into object matrix by using this:

```
Object[,] values = (Object[,])worksheet.UsedRange.Cells.Value;
```

The issue is because in the excel I sometimes have decimal numbers and sometimes percent numbers.

When calling `Cells.Value`, I am getting percent number in decimal format. For *example* for the number 60.32% I get 0.6032 in values and I would like to keep this decimal format and get 60.32%.

I've tried by using `worksheet.UsedRange.Cells.Text` but it returns me `null` as `UsedRange.Cells` has different formats in excel.

So, how could I keep percentage in the number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Excel Percentages Converted to Decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139292/c-sharp-excel-percentages-converted-to-decimals)

Comment: No, UsedRange has different formats it will return me null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159232/how-to-read-percentage-value-with-sign-from-excel-file-using-closedxml

Answer (score 0):

For **ClosedXML** API: Instead of `UsedRange.Cells.Value` try with `UsedRange.Cells.GetFormattedString()`

If you are working with **interop** API, you need to do some extra work on your side.

- If all cells in range are formatted as percentage, then you can get format using `Range.NumberFormat` and then accordingly you can multiply each cell value by 100 and appending '%' character to the end.
- `Range.NumberFormat` will return null, if cells present in range are of different types.Then you need to iterate through each cell present in that particular range. Check NumberFormat for particular cell (**E.g.** `((Range)wks.Cells[1,1]).NumberFormat`) and perform operation accordingly.

Comment: I don't have Cells.GetFormattedString() method.

Comment: I am using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: Ok, thanks. I knew that for interop I can iterate through each cell. With this: Cells.Text , I am getting the right format. I was afraid that it will take me too much time for the iteration, but luckily it won't as there is not so much used cells in the sheets.